# asyncio 2 workers RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to learning asyncio, any tips greatly appreciated. I am struggling with something super basic on how to create 2 processes taking turns printing messages.

```
import asyncio


async def firstWorker():
    print(f'asyncio message worker 1 Hello!')
    asyncio.sleep(2)


async def secondWorker():
    print(f'asyncio message worker 2 Hello!')
    asyncio.sleep(2)

# Running the ven_client in the Python AsyncIO Event Loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(firstWorker())
    asyncio.ensure_future(secondWorker())
    loop.run_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    print("Closing Loop")
    loop.close()
```

This will throw an error, and wont continue to run:

```
asyncio message worker 1 Hello!

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "basic.py", line 6
    asyncio.sleep(2)
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
asyncio message worker 2 Hello!

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "basic.py", line 11
    asyncio.sleep(2)
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sleep' was never awaited
```

Comment: As you're going into this, I want to offer some words of encouragement.  `asyncio` and `await` are not simple, familiar concepts.  It really takes time to wrap your head around the concepts.  Don't be discouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, use

```
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thank you, when I implement this the halts after the first 2 prints. `Nothing more asyncio message worker 1 Hello!
asyncio message worker 2 Hello!`

Comment: Any ideas to try?

Comment: What else would you expect?  All of your work is finished.  End of line.

Comment: well I guess your right I thought I could create something that could just continuously print messages from each worker every 2 seconds.

Comment: I think its back to the drawing board for me

Comment: Can asyncio do something simple like this? Obviously my real world task is a little more complicated

Comment: Use a simple while loop @HenryHub

Comment: Is that using while True loop inside each worker? I get it, any chance you could post an answer?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens?  If you expect code to loop, then you really need to include a loop....

Comment: Thanks for all the help I'm afk at the moment will try when I can :  )